# Programmatically accessing a storyboard button?

Tags: ios5, xcode4

I've been searching for a day now and have not found the magic words to google with...

I have a UIBarButtonItem that has been placed with the storyboard.  Is there any way to access the button programmatically? (to, say, change the enabled flag) Or am I "starting over" and creating the button programmatically from the beginning?

Answer (score 4):

You can create `IBOutlet` of that button in your .h file.

Just ctrl + drag from your UIBarButtonItem to your .h file. Then simply access it like any other property

```
self.barButton = ...
```

---

To programmatically find all the buttons in view:
Optionally, check `button.tag` to find specific button.

```
NSArray *arrSubviews = [self.view subviews];
for(UIView *tmpView in arrSubviews)
{
    if([tmpView isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        // Optionally, check button.tag
        if(tmpView.tag == 2) {
            // Do some action    
        }

        // Do some action on UIButton like
        [tmpView setHidden: isHidden];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not "programmatically", that's through IB. I have the same issue and cannot use your solution since my buttons are on a separate nib file and will be used in various places.

Comment: Perfect, you get +1 sir